# QGIS understanding of evaluation units

Tags: qgis, raster

I am a game developer and I am not good in GIS, but it contains very useful data for our future project, my final goal is to generate height map for terrain render. I found a way to extract (convert) opened ASC file raster layer form 32 bit to 4 8 bits images, I changing min-max in layer properties, but I don't understand what units it uses
[image]

-24 to 74 ... I have no idea what that means.

P.S. I was searching forum for answer but did not find it, maybe I just don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, you haven't stated what data you are using, or where you got it, so we can't do more than guess. You ought to be looking at the metadata associated with the DEM, to determine if is meters, feet, tenths of meters, or some other value based on an arbitrary zero point.

Comment: There are no "generic" GIS raster units. This depends on the dataset you are using and needs to be clarified with the source of your data.

Comment: Thank you for answers! I just thought that file could contain the information about units and I can see it some where in QGIS tool.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [metadata](https://data.noaa.gov/harvest/object/d9ef2c4e-adc4-4797-b3f8-c0649c1b9bfb) found from a link on the NOAA page for the [mobile_al_mhw dataset](https://data.noaa.gov/dataset/06d1252f-435b-487e-85e1-7698f463ed68)

The unit of z is metres.

```
<gmi:MI_CoverageDescription>
    <gmd:attributeDescription gco:nilReason="unknown"/>
    <gmd:contentType gco:nilReason="unknown"/>
    <gmd:dimension>
        <gmd:MD_Band>
            <gmd:sequenceIdentifier>
            <gco:MemberName>
            <gco:aName>
            <gco:CharacterString>z</gco:CharacterString>
            </gco:aName>
            <gco:attributeType>
            <gco:TypeName>
            <gco:aName>
            <gco:CharacterString>float</gco:CharacterString>
            </gco:aName>
            </gco:TypeName>
            </gco:attributeType>
            </gco:MemberName>
            </gmd:sequenceIdentifier>
            <gmd:descriptor>
            <gco:CharacterString>z</gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:descriptor>
            <gmd:units xlink:href="http://example.org/someUnitsDictionary.xml#meters"/>
        </gmd:MD_Band>
    </gmd:dimension>
    <gmd:dimension>
        <gmd:MD_Band>
            <gmd:sequenceIdentifier>
            <gco:MemberName>
            <gco:aName>
            <gco:CharacterString>x</gco:CharacterString>
            </gco:aName>
            <gco:attributeType>
            <gco:TypeName>
            <gco:aName>
            <gco:CharacterString>double</gco:CharacterString>
            </gco:aName>
            </gco:TypeName>
            </gco:attributeType>
            </gco:MemberName>
            </gmd:sequenceIdentifier>
            <gmd:descriptor>
            <gco:CharacterString>x</gco:CharacterString>
            </gmd:descriptor>
            <gmd:units xlink:href="http://example.org/someUnitsDictionary.xml#degrees_east"/>
        </gmd:MD_Band>
    </gmd:dimension>
    <gmd:dimension>
        <gmd:MD_Band>
        <gmd:sequenceIdentifier>
        <gco:MemberName>
        <gco:aName>
        <gco:CharacterString>y</gco:CharacterString>
        </gco:aName>
        <gco:attributeType>
        <gco:TypeName>
        <gco:aName>
        <gco:CharacterString>double</gco:CharacterString>
        </gco:aName>
        </gco:TypeName>
        </gco:attributeType>
        </gco:MemberName>
        </gmd:sequenceIdentifier>
        <gmd:descriptor>
        <gco:CharacterString>y</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:descriptor>
        <gmd:units xlink:href="http://example.org/someUnitsDictionary.xml#degrees_north"/>
        </gmd:MD_Band>
    </gmd:dimension>
</gmi:MI_CoverageDescription>
```

Comment: Wow, the answer is so simple))) Thank you! I just been confused by coordinates of map which looks like -88.234,29.978, and I thought the height (z coordinate) should be the same.

Comment: Also, could you please say how exactly you understand that z is meters, I've read the pdf file with description for map but not found exact information about that.

Comment: If you follow the metadata link in my answer it goes to an XML document.  The units of the three axes are shown.  I've updated my answer to show the relevant section.